# How does pushing an Item in stack in Java and python work without causing memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, stack, queue

I'm working through **Chapter 3 (stacks and queues) of Cracking the Coding interview** and the implementation of `push()` has me a bit confused.

I made a diagram to show how I expected it to work and how it seems to actually work.

Based on my mental model of how variable assignment works, I would have expected a memory leak because the reference to the previous top node is lost.

I made another diagram on the right to try and "convince myself" why there is no memory leak. But I need an actual explanation of why that is the case?

My question is:

1. Can someone please explain why the code snippet doesn't cause a memory leak?
2. Python is my preferred programming language so I would also really like to know if the equivalent code snippet in python behaves the same way.

```java
// java implementation
public void push(T item) {
    StackNode<T> t = new StackNode<t>(item)
    t.next = top
    top = t
}
```

```py
# python implementation
def push(self, item):
    node = Node(item)
    node.next= self.top
    self.top = node
```

[image]

Comment: Since `top` is just a reference to an object, after execution of `t.next = top` `t.next` will point not to `top` but to the element (item) to which `top` points.

Answer (score 0):

The right part of the image is actually what happens as well. `top` is a reference to an object in memory. So when you do `t.next = top`, the `t.next` part also points to the memory referenced by `top`. So at this point, both `t.next` and `top` point to the same memory location. (`t.next` does not point to `top`, it points to the memory where `top` points to). Next, with the assignment `top = t`, you change the reference to which `top` is pointing from `item` to `t`. So the result will not be like the left part of the image.

(**NOTE**: The diagram should be having another box like `Box(t) ----> Box(new node)`, similar to `Box(top) ----> Box(item)`. Currently you have considered the variable, `t` and the memory it references as a single entity, that might have caused the confusion)

Answer (score 0):

Java developers usually do not track the elements of collections that were left hanging in memory alone.

Java manages its memory in an automatic way. Every time you leave an object which is not reachable by any other essence, it becomes  "garbage" and a candidate to be deleted by Java's garbage collector,  or GC.

Memory leak is an attribute of languages without automatic memory management (Pascal, C, bare C++).

Leaving an object "orphaned", i.e. without any variablies pointing to it, doesn't mean that Java's GC starts garbage collection immidiately. For machine's resource optimization, it splits all orphaned objects into so-called generations.

Garbage collection starts with deleting the first-time generation. If they all were deleted, GC moves to deletion of second-time generation.

For further reading, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/generations.html

You may explicitly call GC at any time with `System.gc()`.

Comment: Note that `System.gc()` just requests for a GC cycle. There is no guarantee that a GC would happen.

Comment: `Every time you leave an object which is not reachable by any other essence, it becomes "garbage" and a candidate to be deleted by Java's garbage collector, or GC.`  - even though this is true, in this question, the `item` is not actually getting unreachable. It would still be referenced by `t.next`. The left part of the image in question is not actually what happens.